# How to run tests against multiple URLs in Python Selenium Pytest Unittest

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, pytest

I want to test multiple URLs one by one on Python Selenium but, for loop doesn't seems to work as expected. It always pick the last URL from the array. I mean "https://url2.com"

```
import re
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# credentials (Hardcoded)
userName = 'user'
passWord = 'password'


class TestingLoginPage(unittest.TestCase):
    test_urls = ['https://url1.com', 'https://url2.com']

    for url in test_urls:

        def setUp(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

        # --- Steps ---
        def test_load_home_page(self):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get(self.url)
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.title_is("Sign in"))
                print(f'Page is loaded within 5 seconds.')
            except:
                print(f'Page loading issue.')

        def test_successful_login(self):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get(self.url)
            driver.find_element_by_id('j_username').send_keys(userName)
            driver.find_element_by_name('j_password').send_keys(passWord)
            driver.find_element_by_name('Submit').click()
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ec.title_is('Dashboard'))
                print(f'User logged in')
            except:
                print(f'User login failed')

        def test_failed_login(self):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get(self.url)
            driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(userName)
            driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('test')
            driver.find_element_by_name('Submit').click()
            try:
                src = driver.page_source
                text_found = re.search(r'wrong username or password', src)
                self.assertNotEqual(text_found, None)
                print(f'Wrong username or password.')
            except:
                print(f'User logged in with wrong credentials, check the Credentials setup')

        def tearDown(self):
            self.driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I tried multiple possibilites but no luck. Since i am new to python i am unable to figure out the issue.

Comment: I'm not a python expert but it looks like you are defining a bunch of methods inside the loop but not actually calling any of them. Try moving the method declarations outside of the `for` loop and then call the methods you want inside the `for` loop and see what happens.